# How to know OpenStack volumes actual size in Ceph storage

Tags: openstack, ceph

I want to know how to get Openstack provisioned instance volumes actual size in Ceph storage. what Ceph operation should be used to get such info.

e.g. we have a volume of 1 TB that only 10 GB consumed so Ceph will store only 10 GB and rest of the volume are not consumed in Ceph. then I want to check in Ceph that this volume consumption is 10 GB
what I found in Ceph it reports only total size using below command

```
red -p volumes info
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

```
rbd du ${pool}/${rbd}
```

displays Provisioned size and used size

Answer (score 1):

On a ceph node you could use the command `rbd [-p pool_name] du`. The default rbd pool name is rbd. If this differs provide the name. This will list the sizes of your images. Depending on the image take this may take a while. While most recent rbd images are quick in reporting their size. You get the current and max size information.